# Nextjs + react-transition-group don't animate

Tags: next.js, react-transition-group

I'am in trouble with nextjs + react-animation-group, I'have follow the docs to implement but doesn't work,  i need to animate a component from opacity 0 to 1 in 2.5 sec. here my test:

https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-group-u5htd

you can see that "Animation div" appear instantly instead with opacity transition, any ideas how to solve?

Thx all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try This :-

pages/_app.js

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  return (
    <SwitchTransition mode='out-in'>
      <CSSTransition key={router.pathname} classNames='page' timeout={300}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </CSSTransition>
    </SwitchTransition>
  );
}
```

global.css

````
.page-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.page-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
.page-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.page-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}```
````

Comment: Can't I use it in module.css?

Answer (score 2):

You need `appear={true}` on your `CSSTransition` tag and add css for appear active. And I think instead of writting css in `<style jsx global>` tag, you should define a new css file and import it

```
.div-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
.div-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 10000ms ease-out;
}
```

you can check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-monad-t65ul), hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi iamhuynq, could you please clarify why `appear={true}` was needed? My `classNames` currently don't get added unless I include the appear prop.